# belongs_to association query method doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

The "association?" query method that the [Rails docs say](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001835) should exist when I create a belongs_to association doesn't actually get created:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

```
>> p = Post.create(:author => Author.create)
>> p.author?
NoMethodError: undefined method `author?' for #<Post:0x2555d28>
```

Is this a bug, are the docs wrong, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: hi what is it that you are trying to achieve? to see if there is an author assosciated with this post?

Comment: Yes, but specifically using the "Post#author?" method described in the documentation.  I realize I can get that information by other means (e.g. p.author in boolean context), but I'm trying to find out why the documented functionality isn't working for me.

Comment: i can't get it to work too, seems like a bug...

Answer (score 1):

Take the question mark off.

```
p.author
```

Comment: Of course that works, but the question is why does "author?" not work.  It's documented that it should.

Answer (score 1):

It only works on boolean attributes, not belongs_to associations.